# Как считать связный список из файла?

Tags: c++, struct

Как осуществить ввод списка из файла?

Задание:

> Записи содержат названия издания, газета или журнал, цена экземпляра. Добавлять новые записи так, чтобы названия были упорядочены по алфавиту.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct spis                 //opisivaem structuru
{
    char name [20];
    int type;
    int cena;
    struct spis *prev;    //ssilka na pred.structuru
    struct spis *next;    //ssilka na sled.structuru
};

void create(void);       //opisanie funkciy
void list(spis *);
void add(void);
void sortt(void);
void addkorr(void);
struct spis *head, *tail;

int main ()
{
    char c;             //peremennaya vibora punkta menu
    while(1)
    {
        system("CLS");
        puts("1 - Sozdat' spisok");
        puts("2 - Posmotret' spisok");
        puts("3 - Dobavit' novuyu structuru v konec spiska");
        puts("4 - Korrekciya spiska s dobavleniem novoy structury");
        puts("5 - Vihod");
        c=_getch();
        switch(c)
        {
        case '1': create(); break;
        case '2': list(head); break;
        case '3': add(); break;
        case '4': addkorr(); break;
        case '5': return 0;
        default: puts("Oshibka vvoda!");
        }
    }
    free(head);                      //Osvobojdenie pamyati
}

void create(void)                   //Funkciya sozdaniya spiska
{
     system("CLS");                //Ochistka ekrana
     spis *p, *pred;               //opisanie ukazateley na structuru
     pred=NULL;
     do                            //cikl sozdaniya spiska
     {
         p=(spis *)malloc(sizeof(spis));                          //videlenie pamyati pod spisok
         cout<<"Nazvanie izdaniya: ";
         cin>>p->name;
         cout<<"Vvedite 0, esli eto jurnal i 1, esli gazeta: ";
         cin>>p->type;
         cout<<"Cena izdaniya: ";
         cin>>p->cena;
         p->prev=pred;                                            //ustanovka svyazey
         if(pred!=NULL)
             pred->next=p;
         else
             head=p;
             pred=p;
          cout<<"Dlya vihoda najmite <esc>";
          cout<<endl<<endl;
     }
     while(getch()!=27);
     tail=p;                                                     //ssilka na konec spiska
     tail->next=NULL;
}

void list(spis *p)                                              //prosmotr spiska
{
    ofstream output;
    output.open("D:\\laba16.txt", ios::out); 
    system("CLS");
    cout<<"             ----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout<<"             є Nazvanie izdaniya є Jurnal=0, Gazeta=1 є Cena izdaniya є\n";
    cout<<"             ----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    output<<"             ----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    output<<"             є Nazvanie izdaniya є Jurnal=0, Gazeta=1 є Cena izdaniya є\n";
    output<<"             ----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    p=head;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\n             є"<<setw(18)<<p->name<<"є"<<setw(20)<<p->type<<"є"<<setw(16)<<p->cena<<"є";
        output<<"\n             є"<<setw(18)<<p->name<<"є"<<setw(20)<<p->type<<"є"<<setw(16)<<p->cena<<"є";
        p=p->next;
    }
    cout<<"\n\nNajmite lubuyu klavishu dlya vihoda v glavnoe menu...";
    output.close();
    getch();
}

void add(void)                                               //dobavlenie novogo spiska v konec structuri
{
    spis *p, *pn;
    system("CLS");
    pn=(spis *)malloc(sizeof(spis));
    cout<<"Nazvanie izdaniya: ";
    cin>>pn->name;
    cout<<"Vvedite 0, esli eto jurnal i 1, esli gazeta: ";
    cin>>pn->type;
    cout<<"Cena izdaniya: ";
    cin>>pn->cena;
    p=tail;                                               //perehod v konec spiska
    pn->prev=tail;
    pn->next=NULL;
    p->next=pn;
    tail=pn;                                            //noviy konec spiska
}

void sortt(void)                                       //sortirovka spiska
{
    spis *p, *pn;
    int j,x,y;
    char d[20];
    do
    {
        j=1;
        p=head;                                      //perehod v nachalo spiska
        pn=p;
        p=p->next;
        while(p!=NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(pn->name, p->name)>0)        //esli pn>p sortiruem
            {
                j=0;
                strcpy(d, pn->name);
                x=pn->type;
                y=pn->cena;
                strcpy(pn->name, p->name);
                pn->type=p->type;
                pn->cena=p->cena;
                strcpy(p->name, d);
                p->type=x;
                p->cena=y;
            }
            pn=p;                                  //perehod k sled.elementu spiska
            p=p->next;
        }
    } 
    while(j==0);
}

void addkorr(void)                             //vstavka novoy structury, korrekciya po alfavitu
{
  spis *p, *pn;
  system("CLS");
  sortt();                                    //vizov sortirovki spiska
  pn=(spis *)malloc(sizeof(spis));
  cout<<"Nazvanie izdaniya: ";
  cin>>pn->name;
  cout<<"Vvedite 0, esli eto jurnal i 1, esli gazeta: ";
  cin>>pn->type;
  cout<<"Cena izdaniya: ";
  cin>>pn->cena;
  int j, ei;
  j=0; ei=0;
  p=head;
  do
  {
      if(strcmp(pn->name, p->name)<=0 && p->prev==NULL && ei==0)   //esli pn<p, eto nachalo spiska i ei=0
      {
          j=1;                                                    //vihod iz cikla
          p->prev=pn;
          pn->prev=NULL;
          pn->next=p;
          head=pn;
          ei=1;
      }
      if(strcmp(pn->name, p->name)<=0 && ei==0)                  //esli pn<p, eto ne nachalo spiska i ei=0
      {
          j=1;
          pn->prev=NULL;
          pn->next=NULL;
          p->prev->next=pn;
          pn->prev=p->prev;
          pn->next=p;
          p->prev=pn;
          ei=1;
      }
      if(p->next==NULL && ei==0)
      {
          j=1;
          pn->prev=NULL;
          pn->next=NULL;
          p->next=pn;
          pn->prev=p;
          ei=1;
      }
      p=p->next;
  }
  while (j==0);
  cout<<"\n\nNoviy spisok dobavlen. Najmite lubuyu klavishu dlya prodoljeniya";
  getch();
}
```

Comment: смысль С++, ООП, не в том, чтоб написать несколько десятков  строк, не имеющих отношения к решению задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Я даже не пытался понять что вы расписали тут... Контейнеры и несовсем контейнеры для хранения данных, в STL есть любого вкуса и предназначения. Чтобы хранить данные от меньшего до большего используем set<> (получится у нас сортировка вставками)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

struct  Edition {      // издание
    string s;        // название
    int p;           // цена

    Edition(const string& name, int price) :s(name), p(price) {}
    // как выводить?...
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const Edition& ed)
    {
        os << ed.s << "   price  == " <<ed.p << endl;
        return os;
    }
};
// как определить что меньше?...
bool operator <(const Edition& e1, const Edition& e2)
{
   return e1.s < e2.s;
}
int main()
{   
    string  in;
    int n;
    std::set<Edition> editions;
    // тут вы должны определиться откуда данные : из файла или из cin...
    // допустим это из cin
    while (cin >> in >> n) {
        editions.emplace(Edition(in, n));
    }    
    //а тут вы можете выводить и в файл и в cout
    copy(editions.begin(), editions.end(), ostream_iterator<Edition>(cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

определив оператор `'<'` просто заносим в `set`, а множество будет содержать элементы в упорядоченном виде. Нам нужно будет определить как выводятся эти элементы и выводить их... А также можно  написать компаратор вместо оператора `<` и обьявлять `обьект set<>` с этим компаратором, но это детали... Важно, чтоб вы старались пользоваться `STL` и программировать по принципу `ООП`